# Software (for windows) to enhance scanned documents?

Tags: windows, jpeg, scanning

Is there any software for windows that can enhance scanned handwritten (black&white) documents (jpegs) for better readability.

I am looking for a software that can do this automatically to a bulk of photos.

--

I am got a lot of photos and i would like to optimize them for readability, i had an iphone scanner app that did that with great results but i am looking for a windows equivalent.

Comment: What tools have you tried that did not achieve your goals. Your requirements are sort of broad free and the ability to do bulk photos automatically ( any automatic work on photos dealing withthe clarity of the image is work I wouldn't trust ).

Comment: I am got a lot of photos and i would like to optimize them for readability, i had an iphone scanner app that did that with great results but i am looking for a windows equivalent.

Comment: Use http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Photoshop Automate (require some efforts).

1. Install Adobe Photoshop
2. Follow [this tutorial](http://voices.yahoo.com/cleaning-scanned-images-photoshop-98923.html?cat=15) to learn how to enhance a scanned single picture in Photoshop
3. Follow [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/166973/how-to-automate-your-workflow-in-adobe-photoshop/) to learn how to record your actions in step 2
4. Now you can process your pictures in bulk using Photoshop Automate

Sample Results:

[image]